# Android 4.1 MediaCodec supported resolutions

Tags: android, video, h.264, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I'm trying to get Android 4.1's new low-level media-features to work for H.264 encoding on an Asus Transformer TF300T tablet. I'm experiencing some strange behavior when I try to increase the resolution of the codec:

```
        MediaFormat mediaFormat = MediaFormat.
                                createVideoFormat("video/mp4v-es", 320, 240); // WORKS
//      MediaFormat mediaFormat = MediaFormat.
//                              createVideoFormat("video/mp4v-es", 640, 480); // DOESN'T WORK

        mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 125000);
        mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, 25);
        mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420Planar);
        mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 5);
        mediaCodec.configure(mediaFormat, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
        mediaCodec.start();
```

In the latter case, I'm getting a IllegalStateException when calling `mediaCodec.getInputBuffers();`. Anyone who has any explanation (or even better: a fix)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Try the the [CamcorderProfile](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/CamcorderProfile.html) API.  Configurations exactly matching one of the ones retrieved from that are likely to work.
2. Clearly in your case there is some combination of resolution *and other parameters* that makes it not work.  I wonder if it is the framerate?  25 is a bit odd, try 29.97 or 30, or maybe 15.  I also wonder if it is the bitrate?  It is is much too low for the resolution, try 500kbit/s.

Comment: Your second hint did the trick, thank you! I'm having a color space problem now, but before asking any questions I will examine the CamcorderProfile API. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I posted another question on the topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703596/mediacodec-and-camera-colorspaces-dont-match

Answer (score 2):

Please checkout below link :

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Check the section "Video Encoding Recommendations". The values are in `pixels` so make sure that the values are supported by the device resolution.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issues, when I worked with MediaRecorder.

You can try to use CamcorderProfile, but from my experience, it doesn't guarantee stable work. 
Also in Android 2.* you can have only two profiles of CamcorderProfile.

These settings are device specific, and you can obtain the best for wide range of devices in experimental way.

**EDIT:** Also you can use H.263 instead of H.264, for your case it should work.