# MediaCodec and Camera: colorspaces don't match

Tags: android, colors, h.264, gstreamer, rtp

I have been trying to get H264 encoding to work with input captured by the camera on an Android tablet using the new low-level [MediaCodec](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html). I have gone through some difficulties with this, since the MediaCodecAPI is poorly documented, but I've gotten something to work at last.

I'm setting up the camera as follows:

```
        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        parameters.setPreviewFormat(ImageFormat.YV12); // <1>
        parameters.setPreviewFpsRange(4000,60000);
        parameters.setPreviewSize(640, 480);            
        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
```

For the encoding part, I'm instantiating the MediaCodec object as follows:

```
    mediaCodec = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType("video/avc");
    MediaFormat mediaFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat("video/avc", 640, 480);
    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 500000);
    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, 15);
    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT,
            MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420Planar); // <2>
    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 5);
    mediaCodec.configure(mediaFormat, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
    mediaCodec.start();
```

The final goal is to create an RTP-stream (and correspond with Skype), but so far I am only streaming the raw H264 directly to my desktop. There I use the following GStreamer-pipeline to show the result:

```
gst-launch udpsrc port=5555 ! video/x-h264,width=640,height=480,framerate=15/1 ! ffdec_h264 ! autovideosink
```

All works well, except for the colors. I need to set 2 colorformats in the computer: one for the camera-preview (line tagged with `<1>`) and one for the MediaCodec-object (tagged with `<2>`)

To determine the acceptable values for the lines `<1>` I used `parameters.getSupportedPreviewFormats()`. From this, I know that the only supported formats on the camera are [ImageFormat.NV21](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat.html#NV21) and [ImageFormat.YV2](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat.html#YV12).

For `<2>`, I retrieved the [MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.html)-object for type *video/avc*, being the integer values 19 (corresponding with [MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420Planar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.html#COLOR_FormatYUV420Planar) and 2130708361 (which doesn't correspond with any value of [MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.html)).

Any other value than the above results in a crash.

Combining these settings gives different results, which I'll show below. Here's the screenshot on Android (i.e. the "real" colors):
[image: Input on Android-tablet]
Here are the results as shown by Gstreamer:

`<1>` = NV21, `<2>` = COLOR_FormatYUV420Planar
[image: Gstreamer-output for NV21-COLOR_FormatYUV420Planar]

`<1>` = NV21, `<2>` = 2130708361
[image: Gstreamer-output for NV21-2130708361]

`<1>` = YV2, `<2>` = COLOR_FormatYUV420Planar
[image: Gstreamer-output for YV2-COLOR_FormatYUV420Planar]

`<1>` = YV2, `<2>` = 2130708361
[image: Gstreamer-output for YV2-2130708361]

As can be seen, none of these are satisfying. The YV2-colorspace looks the most promising, but it looks like red (Cr) and blue (Cb) are inverted. The NV21 looks interlaced I guess (however, I'm no expert in this field).

Since the purpose is to communicate with Skype, I assume I shouldn't change the decoder (i.e. the Gstreamer-command), right? Is this to be solved in Android and if so: how? Or can this be solved by adding certain RTP payload information? Any other suggestion?

Comment: Looks like 2130708361 corresponds to [COLOR_FormatSurface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.html#COLOR_FormatSurface).  You must be using API version > 17.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved it by swapping the byteplanes myself on Android level, using a simple function:

```
public byte[] swapYV12toI420(byte[] yv12bytes, int width, int height) {
    byte[] i420bytes = new byte[yv12bytes.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < width*height; i++)
        i420bytes[i] = yv12bytes[i];
    for (int i = width*height; i < width*height + (width/2*height/2); i++)
        i420bytes[i] = yv12bytes[i + (width/2*height/2)];
    for (int i = width*height + (width/2*height/2); i < width*height + 2*(width/2*height/2); i++)
        i420bytes[i] = yv12bytes[i - (width/2*height/2)];
    return i420bytes;
}
```

Comment: FWIW, some devices accept COLOR_FormatYUV420Planar, some accept COLOR_FormatYUV420SemiPlanar.

Comment: In 4.3 (API 18) you can use the Surface preview rather than a ByteBuffer.  This avoids the need to correct the color planes, and is portable.  See the CameraToMpegTest sample on http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/

Comment: yeah, 500, 1000 msec, please delete this answer

Comment: @user25, This question and answer is > 5 years old. We all knew the image format was wrong, but the function to change it wasn't documented - possibly didn't even exist. If you are still having a similar problem you should write a new answer because other people are sure to be having the same problem.

Answer (score 6):

I think it's more efficient to swap the values in place.

```
        int wh4 = input.length/6; //wh4 = width*height/4
        byte tmp;
        for (int i=wh4*4; i<wh4*5; i++)
            {
            tmp = input[i];
            input[i] = input[i+wh4];
            input[i+wh4] = tmp;
            }
```

Maybe even better, you can instead replace

```
            inputBuffer.put(input);
```

With the 3 planar slices in the correct order

```
            inputBuffer.put(input, 0, wh4*4);
            inputBuffer.put(input, wh4*5, wh4);
            inputBuffer.put(input, wh4*4, wh4);
```

I think that should only have a tiny overhead

Comment: with `cameraParamters.setPreviewFormat(ImageFormat.YV12);` or `(ImageFormat.YV12)` your solution does nothing  (**With the 3 planar slices in the correct order**)

Answer (score 3):

It seems Android is transmitting in YV12, but the format set in the H264 headers is YUV420. These formats are equal except the U and V channels are in different order, which explains the swapping of red and blue.

Best would be of course to fix the setting on the Android side. But if there is no way to set compatible settings for camera and encoder, you will have to force the format on the GStreamer side.

This can be done by adding `capssetter` element after the `ffdec_h264`

`... ! ffdec_h264 ! capssetter caps="video/x-raw-yuv, format=(fourcc)YV12" ! colorspace ! ...`

Comment: Could I also fix this by adding a GStreamer pipe on the android side? Given that the above uses up to 50% of the CPU, do you think there'll be enough resources to do that, and eventually do some H264 decoding in parallel?

Comment: android default is NV21, not YV12

Answer (score 0):

With ImageFormat.NV21 set on camera and COLOR_FormatYUV420Planar for encoder , similar blue shadow is seen to overlap in my case. As I understand the above swap function cannot be used in my case, any suggestions on an algorithm that can be used for this? 
ps: Its a complete black screen at decoder when the camera preview format is set as YV12

Comment: The above swap will only work if you set ImageFormat.YV12 on the camera side. Conversion from NV21 will be a lot more complex since it includes an interleaved plane (see http://www.fourcc.org/yuv.php). If I understand correctly, this interleaved plane has swapped U and V values as well, so the swap function may come in handy anyway (slightly modified since the width and height will be only half).

Answer (score 0):

I've used the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17983502/how-can-i-convert-android-bitmap-to-nv12-color-format/66902368) to convert the camera images to video using media encoder, which caused the same kind of issue.

So referring this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV#Y%E2%80%B2UV420p_(and_Y%E2%80%B2V12_or_YV12)_to_RGB888_conversion) I modified the code [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66902368/3192693) and the output seems to be working fine. Instead of uvuv byte order, changed the byte order to uuuuuvvvv ..