# How to use Android MediaCodec encode Camera data(YUV420sp)

Tags: android, android-camera, h.264, video-encoding

Thank you for your focus!
I want to use Android MediaCodec APIs to encode the video frame which aquired from Camera,
unfortunately, I have not success to do that! I still not familiar with the MediaCodec API。
The follow is my codes,I need your help to figure out what I should do.

1、The Camera setting:

```
Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
parameters.setPreviewFormat(ImageFormat.NV21);
parameters.setPreviewSize(320, 240);
mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
```

2、Set the encoder:

```
private void initCodec() {
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(mVideoFile, false);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mMediaCodec = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType("video/avc");
    MediaFormat mediaFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat("video/avc",
            320,
            240);
    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 125000);
    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, 15);
    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT,
            MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420Planar);
    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 5);
    mMediaCodec.configure(mediaFormat,
            null,
            null,
            MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
    mMediaCodec.start();
    inputBuffers = mMediaCodec.getInputBuffers();
    outputBuffers = mMediaCodec.getOutputBuffers();
}

private void encode(byte[] data) {
    int inputBufferIndex = mMediaCodec.dequeueInputBuffer(0);
    if (inputBufferIndex >= 0) {
        ByteBuffer inputBuffer = inputBuffers[inputBufferIndex];
        inputBuffer.clear();
        inputBuffer.put(data);
        mMediaCodec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex, 0, data.length, 0, 0);
    } else {
        return;
    }

    MediaCodec.BufferInfo bufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
    int outputBufferIndex = mMediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, 0);
    Log.i(TAG, "outputBufferIndex-->" + outputBufferIndex);
    do {
        if (outputBufferIndex >= 0) {
            ByteBuffer outBuffer = outputBuffers[outputBufferIndex];
            System.out.println("buffer info-->" + bufferInfo.offset + "--"
                    + bufferInfo.size + "--" + bufferInfo.flags + "--"
                    + bufferInfo.presentationTimeUs);
            byte[] outData = new byte[bufferInfo.size];
            outBuffer.get(outData);
            try {
                if (bufferInfo.offset != 0) {
                    fos.write(outData, bufferInfo.offset, outData.length
                            - bufferInfo.offset);
                } else {
                    fos.write(outData, 0, outData.length);
                }
                fos.flush();
                Log.i(TAG, "out data -- > " + outData.length);
                mMediaCodec.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufferIndex, false);
                outputBufferIndex = mMediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo,
                        0);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (outputBufferIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED) {
            outputBuffers = mMediaCodec.getOutputBuffers();
        } else if (outputBufferIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
            MediaFormat format = mMediaCodec.getOutputFormat();
        }
    } while (outputBufferIndex >= 0);
}
```

I guess the problem occurred in the encoder method,the method will be used in the Camera Preview Callback ,like

```
initCodec();

//mCamera.setPreviewCallback(new MyPreviewCallback());
mCamera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        encode(data);
    }
});
```

I just have no idea how to do it correctly  with the MediaCodec API.Can you give me some advice or links about it?

Thank you!

Comment: did you use it to just record video without audio, I would like to know how to use it with MediaMuxer to record video and audio

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have solved the problem.As follows：

```
private synchronized void encode(byte[] data)
{
    inputBuffers = mMediaCodec.getInputBuffers();// here changes
    outputBuffers = mMediaCodec.getOutputBuffers();

    int inputBufferIndex = mMediaCodec.dequeueInputBuffer(-1);
    Log.i(TAG, "inputBufferIndex-->" + inputBufferIndex);
    //......
```

And next,you will find your encoded video color is not right, for more information,please go to here [MediaCodec and Camera: colorspaces don't match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703596/mediacodec-and-camera-colorspaces-dont-match)

Comment: i got this error.how to solve this pblm....java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.media.MediaCodec error point out this line :  mMediaCodec = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType("video/avc");

Comment: @Aravi It seems that you try to use MediaCodec on Android with API < 16

Answer (score 7):

The YUV420 formats output by the camera are incompatible with the formats accepted by the MediaCodec AVC encoder.  In the best case, it's essentially NV12 vs. NV21 (U and V planes are reversed), requiring a manual reordering.  In the worst case, as of Android 4.2, the encoder input format may be device-specific.

You're better off using [MediaRecorder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html) to connect the camera hardware to the encoder.

**Update:**
It's now possible to pass the camera's Surface preview to `MediaCodec`, instead of using the YUV data in the `ByteBuffer`.  This is faster and more portable.  See the CameraToMpegTest sample [here](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/).

Comment: Thank you for your help.I have recorded a video file,but the file data is not correct.The starting data is right,they are h.264 frame data,but about three frames later ,h.264 frame data are all filled with 0.May be the file buffer is wrong,I think,but it can not be 0

Comment: Hi, @fadden. About the "You're better off using MediaRecorder to connect the camera hardware to the encoder.", is there any sample code for it ? Thanks.

Comment: MediaRecorder, Surface doesn't allow to process frames before recording and why do you think it's faster? I think author knows about MediaRecord but as you see he asked about camera frames