# How to convert onPreviewFrame to mp4 video

Tags: android, android-camera, android-mediarecorder, android-mediacodec

I setup a camera preview with a onPreviewFrame call back, I would like to know, "how to encode the onPreviewFrame data onto a mp4 video file?"

Something that I know so far is that Android 4.1 have a MediaCodec(which is an decoder and encoder).
Is the MediaCodec class enough for encoding the onPreviewFrame data onto a mp4 video? If so, what are the steps to accomplish this?

thanks, would appreciate any comments or opinions or suggestions,

Comment: Hi xiaowoo, I am also facing same issue. Have you got the solution? If yes, then please share.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your device has mp4 codecs installed, `MediaCodec` can handle this. You can use [`createEncoderByType()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html#createEncoderByType%28java.lang.String%29) to create a mime-specific encoder. You're probably looking for `"video/mp4v-es"` as the parameter.

For a brief overview of the basics, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17232477/how-to-use-android-mediacodec-encode-camera-datayuv420sp). You can find more detailed tutorials, even full implementations of `MediaCodec`, on the web.

Comment: As noted in the answers to the question linked above, it can be a bit of a challenge to get everything right on 4.1 (e.g. camera and mediacodec YUV formats are different).  For 4.3 and later it's easy -- see CameraToMpegTest on http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/ .

Comment: any  example how to use MediaCodec for recording byte arrays?

Comment: @fadden CameraToMpegTest  doesn't use bytes from onPreviewFrame, it uses Surface... if you read question again we talk about onPreviewFrame - raw frame byte arrays

Comment: Take a look at https://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#EncodeDecodeTest -- it's an Android CTS test that generates YUV data, encodes it, decodes it, and compares it to the original. This is significantly slower than feeding the camera output directly into MediaCodec. The OP seemed to want to encode camera data, which is why I pointed them in that direction. But if you have YUV data from some other source, the above code will show you what to do. Bear in mind you must use a MediaCodec-supported YUV layout, so you may need to convert the image data.