# MediaCodec returns -1,-2,-3 in first seconds

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

I use MediaCodec to decode video data, but when I use dequeueOutputBuffer method ,get the result MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED,MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED and MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER in the first seconds.I want get the normal result of it as soon as I use this method.

```
String mime = format.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME);
mMediaCodec = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(mime);
mMediaCodec.configure(format, mSurface , null , 0 );
mMediaCodec.start();
try{
    ByteBuffer[] inputBuffers = mMediaCodec.getInputBuffers();
    ByteBuffer[] outputBuffers = mMediaCodec.getOutputBuffers();
    int inputBufferIndex = mMediaCodec.dequeueInputBuffer(TLMediaCodec.TIMEOUT_USEC);
    if (inputBufferIndex >= 0) {
        ByteBuffer inputBuffer = inputBuffers[inputBufferIndex];
        inputBuffer.clear();
        inputBuffer.put(data);
        mMediaCodec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex, 0, data.length, ultimestamp, 0);
        int outputBufferIndex = mMediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(mBufferInfo, 100);

        if (outputBufferIndex >= 0)
        {
            try
            {
                mVideoDecodeDelay = System.currentTimeMillis() - mVideoDecodeDelay;
                boolean render = mBufferInfo.size > 0;
                mMediaCodec.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufferIndex, render);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                TLLogger.trace(TAG, "decodeOutput failed -- > " + e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else if (outputBufferIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED)
        {
            outputBuffers = mMediaCodec.getOutputBuffers();
        }
        else if (outputBufferIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED)
        {
            MediaFormat format = mMediaCodec.getOutputFormat();
        }
    }
} catch{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

above is my code,I could not find any dismiss to improve this problem.
Thank you for help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's normal.  You don't send one frame into MediaCodec and get a frame out; you pass a series of frames in and pull them out as they become available.  Some latency between `start()` and the availability of the first frame is expected ([e.g. this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21440820/)).  If you would rather be notified than poll, try the newer asynchronous API methods.

See the "basic usage" notes near the top of the [bigflake page](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/).