# H264 streamed video stutter and freeze with MediaCodec, Android 4.1.2

Tags: java, android, multithreading, video, ffmpeg

I have been trying my heart out to remove the stutter from an android RTSP client. 
Here is my setup

1. FFMPEG server streams a live video on Win7. The video is 1200x900 in size. The video streamed is in H264 format.
2. I receive the video packets on android (4.1.2) clinet under JNI which pushes the packet to java - Device is a Samsung Tab4
3. Packets are decoded using MediaCodec. Once call from JNI to push the packets into MediaCodec, another thread in Java tries to de-queue the data and display them to a SurfaceView (its a GLSurfaceView)

Despite my efforts of using queue to buffer the packets, changing wait times to 0,-1, 1000000, i am unable to get a clean streamed video. I understand that there is some packet loss (1% to 10%), but I am getting a broken video, with stutter (some call it even jitter). Green patches, pink screens, gray slices. You name it, it is there, the problem seems to be exaggerated when there is a fast movement in the video.
At the moment I am not sure where the problem lies, I tried a windows version of the client (with ffmpeg decoding) and it works smoothly despite the packet loss.

What am I doing wrong? Any guidance is appreciated.
Below is the client end code for Android and the server end FFMPEG settings I read from a config file.

```
// Function called from JNI 
    public int decodeVideo(byte[] data, int size, long presentationTimeUs, boolean rtpMarker, int flag)
        {
            if(vdecoder == null)
                return -1;
            if(currVInbufIdx == -1) {
                vdecoderInbufIdx = vdecoder.dequeueInputBuffer(1000000); //1000000/*1s*/
                if(vdecoderInbufIdx < 0) {
                    Log.d("log","decodeVideo@1: frame dropped");
                    vdecoderRet = -1;
                    return vdecoderRet;
                }
                currVInbufIdx = vdecoderInbufIdx;
                currVPts = presentationTimeUs;
                currVFlag = flag;
                inputVBuffers[currVInbufIdx].clear();
            }

            vdecoderPos = inputVBuffers[currVInbufIdx].position();
            vdecoderRemaining = inputVBuffers[currVInbufIdx].remaining();
            if(flag==currVFlag && vdecoderRemaining >= size && currVPts == presentationTimeUs
                    && rtpMarker == false
                    /*&&(pos < vbufferLevel || vbufferLevel<=0)*/) 
            {
                /* Queue without decoding */
                inputVBuffers[currVInbufIdx].put(data, 0,size);
            } 
            else 
            {

                if(flag==currVFlag && vdecoderRemaining >= size && currVPts == presentationTimeUs
                        && rtpMarker) 
                {
                    inputVBuffers[currVInbufIdx].put(data, 0, size);
                    queued = true;
                }
                Log.d("log", "decodeVideo: submit,"
                        + " pts=" + Long.toString(currVPts)
                        + " position="+inputVBuffers[currVInbufIdx].position()
                        + " capacity="+inputVBuffers[currVInbufIdx].capacity()
                        + " VBIndex="+currVInbufIdx
                        );
                vdecoder.queueInputBuffer(currVInbufIdx, 0, inputVBuffers[currVInbufIdx].position(), currVPts, currVFlag);

                //
                vdecoderInbufIdx = vdecoder.dequeueInputBuffer(1000000);//1000000/*1s*/
                if(vdecoderInbufIdx >= 0) 
                {
                    currVInbufIdx = vdecoderInbufIdx;
                    currVPts = presentationTimeUs;
                    currVFlag = flag;
                    inputVBuffers[currVInbufIdx].clear();
                    //if(queued == false) 
                    { 
                        inputVBuffers[vdecoderInbufIdx].put(data, 0, size);

                    }

                } 
                else 
                {
                    currVInbufIdx = -1;
                    currVPts = -1;
                    vdecoderRet = -1;
                    Log.d("log","decodeVideo@2: frame dropped");                        
                }
            }               
            return vdecoderRet;
        }
```

And here we have the thread that calls for a render

```
// Function at android. Called by a separate thread.
    private void videoRendererThreadProc() {

            if(bufinfo == null)
                bufinfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
            videoRendered = false;

            Log.d("log", "videoRenderer started.");

            while(!Thread.interrupted() && !quitVideoRenderer) 
            {

                Log.d("log", "videoRendererThreadProc");

                outbufIdx = vdecoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufinfo,1000000);//500000
                switch (outbufIdx)
                {
                case MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED:
                    Log.d("log", "decodeVideo: output buffers changed.");
                    // outputBuffers = vdecoder.getOutputBuffers();
                    break;
                case MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED:
                    Log.d("log", "decodeVideo: format changed - " + vdecoder.getOutputFormat());
                    break;
                case MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER:
                    // Log.d("log", "decodeVideo: try again later.");
                    break;
                default:

                    // decoded or rendered
                    videoRendered = true;
                    vdecoder.releaseOutputBuffer(outbufIdx, true);
                    //Log.d("log", "decodeVideo: Rendering...!!!.");    
                }
            }

            // flush decoder
            //vdecoder.queueInputBuffer(0, 0, 0, 0, MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM);

            outbufIdx = vdecoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufinfo, 1000000);//10000
            if(outbufIdx >= 0) 
            {
                vdecoder.releaseOutputBuffer(outbufIdx, true);      
            }   
            bufinfo = null;
            videoRendered = false;
            //
            Log.d("log", "videoRenderer terminated.");
        }
```

And the ffmpeg setting at server at as follows.

```
[slices] =  4       # --slices
[threads] = 4       # --threads   
[profile] = high        # --profile main|baseline
[preset] = faster       # --preset faster|ultrafast
[tune] = zerolatency    # --tune
```

Comment: "I tried a windows version of the client (with ffmpeg decoding) and it works smoothly despite the packet loss." Nope, it does not. Reduce the internet speed or add packet loss to the traffic and it will behave the same