# How to live broadcast from Android

Tags: android, video, video-streaming, rtmp, android-mediacodec

I want to do live broadcasting in the way Periscope is doing it. I did a quick search online and found a bunch of libraries like ffmpeg that use native libraries but according to MediaCodec encoding should be supported straight out of the box with the Android SDK right?

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html

So I was wondering why are external native libraries needed for encoding?

Also I tried some libraries but they seem to be too slow especially for high bitrates (I get 16 fps with 1280x720 at 2500Kbps on a Nexus 5X and I was hoping to achieve 1080), how do the popular broadcasting apps do this?

With so much processing involved it seems like its not possible to achieve good quality streaming with a regular phone (not top of the line).

Comment: External libraries are not needed for encoding, but you'll need a way to convert a raw H.264 stream into something suitable for broadcast. See Grafika (https://github.com/google/grafika) for MediaCodec encoding examples.

Comment: @fadden what do you mean exactly? Like making it a FLV for RTMP? You also dont need a native library (i.e. NDK) for that, right? Also what's the benefit of those native libraries?

Comment: I would recommend https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer by Google.

Comment: @HossamAlaa ExoPlayer is for playing, I need broadcasting from the phone to a media server

Comment: Have you tried to use libstreaming? You can stream using RTP over UDP in H.264, H.263, AAC and AMR encoders.

Comment: @NizaSiwale I tried to use it to stream at high resolutions but it seems to me they dont support HD, I got a unsupported VideoQuality with 1280x720

Comment: What was the encoder you tried to use for libstream when it gave you the unsupported videoQuality error

Comment: @NizaSiwale I used H264. I just tried the sample as it is explained on their github page, but with the config I posted.

Comment: hi i have done libstreaming with https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming-examples this library with wowoza server.

Comment: I looked at the code for libStream and I found that if you goto line 128 of theH264Stream class you're find that if(mQuality.resX>=640), the library falls back as the MediaCodec API gets slow with high resolutions. Have you tried to use FFMpeg?

Answer (score 1):

The MediaCodec API tends to get slow with high resolution streams. I'd suggest you should use FFmpeg, there is a good java wrapper called [JavaCV](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv) (it works on android too). Here is a short sample that should get you going

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {


    private PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;

    private String ffmpeg_link = "rtmp://live:live@128.122.151.108:1935/live/test.flv";

    private volatile FFmpegFrameRecorder recorder;
    boolean recording = false;
    long startTime = 0;

    private int sampleAudioRateInHz = 44100;
    private int imageWidth = 320;
    private int imageHeight = 240;
    private int frameRate = 30;

    private Thread audioThread;
    volatile boolean runAudioThread = true;
    private AudioRecord audioRecord;
    private AudioRecordRunnable audioRecordRunnable;

    private CameraView cameraView;
    private IplImage yuvIplimage = null;

    private Button recordButton;
    private LinearLayout mainLayout;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initLayout();
        initRecorder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (mWakeLock == null) {
            PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE); 
            mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK, LOG_TAG); 
            mWakeLock.acquire(); 
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (mWakeLock != null) {
            mWakeLock.release();
            mWakeLock = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        recording = false;
    }


    private void initLayout() {

        mainLayout = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.record_layout);

        recordButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.recorder_control);
        recordButton.setText("Start");
        recordButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        cameraView = new CameraView(this);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(imageWidth, imageHeight);        
        mainLayout.addView(cameraView, layoutParam);
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "added cameraView to mainLayout");
    }

    private void initRecorder() {
        Log.w(LOG_TAG,"initRecorder");

        if (yuvIplimage == null) {
            // Recreated after frame size is set in surface change method
            yuvIplimage = IplImage.create(imageWidth, imageHeight, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 2);
            //yuvIplimage = IplImage.create(imageWidth, imageHeight, IPL_DEPTH_32S, 2);

            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "IplImage.create");
        }

        recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder(ffmpeg_link, imageWidth, imageHeight, 1);
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "FFmpegFrameRecorder: " + ffmpeg_link + " imageWidth: " + imageWidth + " imageHeight " + imageHeight);

        recorder.setFormat("flv");
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "recorder.setFormat(\"flv\")");

        recorder.setSampleRate(sampleAudioRateInHz);
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "recorder.setSampleRate(sampleAudioRateInHz)");

        // re-set in the surface changed method as well
        recorder.setFrameRate(frameRate);
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "recorder.setFrameRate(frameRate)");

        // Create audio recording thread
        audioRecordRunnable = new AudioRecordRunnable();
        audioThread = new Thread(audioRecordRunnable);
    }

    // Start the capture
    public void startRecording() {
        try {
            recorder.start();
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            recording = true;
            audioThread.start();
        } catch (FFmpegFrameRecorder.Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void stopRecording() {
        // This should stop the audio thread from running
        runAudioThread = false;

        if (recorder != null && recording) {
            recording = false;
            Log.v(LOG_TAG,"Finishing recording, calling stop and release on recorder");
            try {
                recorder.stop();
                recorder.release();
            } catch (FFmpegFrameRecorder.Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            recorder = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // Quit when back button is pushed
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            if (recording) {
                stopRecording();
            }
            finish();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (!recording) {
            startRecording();
            Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Start Button Pushed");
            recordButton.setText("Stop");
        } else {
            stopRecording();
            Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Stop Button Pushed");
            recordButton.setText("Start");
        }
    }

    //---------------------------------------------
    // audio thread, gets and encodes audio data
    //---------------------------------------------
    class AudioRecordRunnable implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Set the thread priority
            android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_AUDIO);

            // Audio
            int bufferSize;
            short[] audioData;
            int bufferReadResult;

            bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleAudioRateInHz, 
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
            audioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, sampleAudioRateInHz, 
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSize);

            audioData = new short[bufferSize];

            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "audioRecord.startRecording()");
            audioRecord.startRecording();

            // Audio Capture/Encoding Loop
            while (runAudioThread) {
                // Read from audioRecord
                bufferReadResult = audioRecord.read(audioData, 0, audioData.length);
                if (bufferReadResult > 0) {
                    //Log.v(LOG_TAG,"audioRecord bufferReadResult: " + bufferReadResult);

                    // Changes in this variable may not be picked up despite it being "volatile"
                    if (recording) {
                        try {
                            // Write to FFmpegFrameRecorder
                            recorder.record(ShortBuffer.wrap(audioData, 0, bufferReadResult));
                        } catch (FFmpegFrameRecorder.Exception e) {
                            Log.v(LOG_TAG,e.getMessage());
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Log.v(LOG_TAG,"AudioThread Finished");

            /* Capture/Encoding finished, release recorder */
            if (audioRecord != null) {
                audioRecord.stop();
                audioRecord.release();
                audioRecord = null;
                Log.v(LOG_TAG,"audioRecord released");
            }
        }
    }

    class CameraView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, PreviewCallback {

        private boolean previewRunning = false;

        private SurfaceHolder holder;
        private Camera camera;

        private byte[] previewBuffer;

        long videoTimestamp = 0;

        Bitmap bitmap;
        Canvas canvas;

        public CameraView(Context _context) {
            super(_context);

            holder = this.getHolder();
            holder.addCallback(this);
            holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            camera = Camera.open();

            try {
                camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                camera.setPreviewCallback(this);

                Camera.Parameters currentParams = camera.getParameters();
                Log.v(LOG_TAG,"Preview Framerate: " + currentParams.getPreviewFrameRate());
                Log.v(LOG_TAG,"Preview imageWidth: " + currentParams.getPreviewSize().width + " imageHeight: " + currentParams.getPreviewSize().height);

                // Use these values
                imageWidth = currentParams.getPreviewSize().width;
                imageHeight = currentParams.getPreviewSize().height;
                frameRate = currentParams.getPreviewFrameRate();                

                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageWidth, imageHeight, Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8);


                /*
                Log.v(LOG_TAG,"Creating previewBuffer size: " + imageWidth * imageHeight * ImageFormat.getBitsPerPixel(currentParams.getPreviewFormat())/8);
                previewBuffer = new byte[imageWidth * imageHeight * ImageFormat.getBitsPerPixel(currentParams.getPreviewFormat())/8];
                camera.addCallbackBuffer(previewBuffer);
                camera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(this);
                */              

                camera.startPreview();
                previewRunning = true;
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                Log.v(LOG_TAG,e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
        }

        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
            Log.v(LOG_TAG,"Surface Changed: width " + width + " height: " + height);

            // We would do this if we want to reset the camera parameters
            /*
            if (!recording) {
                if (previewRunning){
                    camera.stopPreview();
                }
                try {
                    //Camera.Parameters cameraParameters = camera.getParameters();
                    //p.setPreviewSize(imageWidth, imageHeight);
                    //p.setPreviewFrameRate(frameRate);
                    //camera.setParameters(cameraParameters);

                    camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                    camera.startPreview();
                    previewRunning = true;
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG,e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }   
            }            
            */

            // Get the current parameters
            Camera.Parameters currentParams = camera.getParameters();
            Log.v(LOG_TAG,"Preview Framerate: " + currentParams.getPreviewFrameRate());
            Log.v(LOG_TAG,"Preview imageWidth: " + currentParams.getPreviewSize().width + " imageHeight: " + currentParams.getPreviewSize().height);

            // Use these values
            imageWidth = currentParams.getPreviewSize().width;
            imageHeight = currentParams.getPreviewSize().height;
            frameRate = currentParams.getPreviewFrameRate();

            // Create the yuvIplimage if needed
            yuvIplimage = IplImage.create(imageWidth, imageHeight, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 2);
            //yuvIplimage = IplImage.create(imageWidth, imageHeight, IPL_DEPTH_32S, 2);
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            try {
                camera.setPreviewCallback(null);

                previewRunning = false;
                camera.release();

            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                Log.v(LOG_TAG,e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

            if (yuvIplimage != null && recording) {
                videoTimestamp = 1000 * (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);

                // Put the camera preview frame right into the yuvIplimage object
                yuvIplimage.getByteBuffer().put(data);

                // FAQ about IplImage:
                // - For custom raw processing of data, getByteBuffer() returns an NIO direct
                //   buffer wrapped around the memory pointed by imageData, and under Android we can
                //   also use that Buffer with Bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer() and copyPixelsToBuffer().
                // - To get a BufferedImage from an IplImage, we may call getBufferedImage().
                // - The createFrom() factory method can construct an IplImage from a BufferedImage.
                // - There are also a few copy*() methods for BufferedImage<->IplImage data transfers.

                // Let's try it..
                // This works but only on transparency
                // Need to find the right Bitmap and IplImage matching types

                /*
                bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(yuvIplimage.getByteBuffer());
                //bitmap.setPixel(10,10,Color.MAGENTA);

                canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
                Paint paint = new Paint(); 
                paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                float leftx = 20; 
                float topy = 20; 
                float rightx = 50; 
                float bottomy = 100; 
                RectF rectangle = new RectF(leftx,topy,rightx,bottomy); 
                canvas.drawRect(rectangle, paint);

                bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(yuvIplimage.getByteBuffer());
                */
                //Log.v(LOG_TAG,"Writing Frame");

                try {

                    // Get the correct time
                    recorder.setTimestamp(videoTimestamp);

                    // Record the image into FFmpegFrameRecorder
                    recorder.record(yuvIplimage);

                } catch (FFmpegFrameRecorder.Exception e) {
                    Log.v(LOG_TAG,e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "The MediaCodec API tends to get slow with high resolution streams." is this right? I would be surprised to hear this since this is the API used to record video on disc and thus save a 1080p video on the device right?

Comment: That seems to be the case, thats why libstream throws that exception. You can read this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19256953/buffering-surface-input-to-mediacodec or look at line 128 of the H264Stream class https://github.com/Ziggeo/android-libstreaming/blob/master/src/net/majorkernelpanic/streaming/video/H264Stream.java

Answer (score 0):

You are right. You have to consider **Android ndk** for processing intensive stuff.

Study and build this [yt watchme](https://github.com/youtube/yt-watchme) and this [minicap](https://github.com/openstf/minicap). also
walk through [webrtc](https://webrtc.org/native-code/android/)

another one [rticonnextdds videodemo android](https://github.com/rticommunity/rticonnextdds-videodemo-android)