# Android onpreviewframe:Preview on image views shows green/pink image on tablet

Tags: image-processing, android-camera, android

I need to get preview from camera and show it on Imageview.. 
The code is done as follows

```
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera){
        yuvimage = new YuvImage(data, parameters.getPreviewFormat(), width, height, null);
        yuvimage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0,0,parameters.getPreviewSize().width,parameters.getPreviewSize().height), 90, outstr);
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(outstr.toByteArray(), 0, outstr.size());        
        camera.addCallbackBuffer(data);
    }
```

This code works fine, the if `bmp` passed to imageview the it displays clear color image on most of the devices, but on a tablet, it shows green/pink image..
If surfaceview is used to show preview directly then it shows clear color preview on all devices..

Any suggestion is appreciated..

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "clear color".  Are colors being changed from (say) red to blue?  Can you post sample images?  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703596/mediacodec-and-camera-colorspaces-dont-match

Answer (score 0):

If the image looks sort of correct, but just has a weird color to it, then I would guess 
that the problem lies with the picture format. I would start is by trying to change parameters.getPreviewFormat() to ImageFormat.NV21 and see if that fixes the problem.

I have used basically the same code before, and never had a problem. (Although you should push the rendering to a separate thread, and probably use RenderScript to convert the pictures).