# Android MediaCodec inverting blue and red

Tags: android, video-streaming, latency, android-mediacodec

Please help me. I have been stuck on this for ages. I am using libstreaming on Android and enforcing the encoding to use the encodeWithMediaCodecMethod2 method in the VideoStream class. This uses MediaCodec class (this has lower latency).  I am using VLC on my computer to receive and play the stream from the phone. The latency is good, but the video is the made up of the wrong colours.
[image]

The red and blue are inverted. Any idea how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#q5 may be relevant.  Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703596/mediacodec-and-camera-colorspaces-dont-match .

Answer (score 0):

Probably u & v planes are swapped in the stream.