# Get Raw data from org.bytedeco.javacv.Frame

Tags: android, android-camera, android-mediacodec, android-ffmpeg, javacpp

I want to get raw data from `javacv` Frame.

I am using `FFmpegFrmaeFilter` to rotate Android camera preview. So, I am pulling Frame from the `FFmpegFrameFilter` and then provides converted `byte[]` to `MediaCodec`.

But, while doing so, I am getting wrong data(green picture).I am taking raw data from `Frame.Image[0].array();`

Is there any other way for fetching raw data from Frame which I can feed to `Mediacodec`.

Comment: An luck?  I too am trying to efficiently get arrays of RGB pixel values out of a Frame, and right now I'm bouncing through a BufferedImage, which is slow.

Answer (score 1):

Green picture most likely means that you pass zeros for chroma components of the image. Android camera usually produces YUV 420 images, where you have width*height array of luminance (Y) followed by U and V, width/2*height/2 each.

`FFmpegFrameFilter` understands different frame formats, but this depends also on some [heuristics](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/blob/master/src/main/java/org/bytedeco/javacv/FFmpegFrameFilter.java#L447) that derives the input pixel format from `Frame` parameters.

`MediaCodec` can receive frames in [flexible YUV 420 format](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities#COLOR_FormatYUV420Flexible), but it is your responsibility to set up the [Image](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/Image) correctly.

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you for your response. I am setting FFmpegFrameFilter with Android NV21 image format. But, still I am not getting proper video. When I have used FFmpegFrameRecorder instead of MediaCodec to store video, then the video is proper. I have also tried OpenCV functions  for video rotation but in that also same issue is happening and I am not able to find out proper format which is compatible for Android.

Comment: As I explained, MediaCodec needs frames wrapped as `CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420Flexible`. You can prepare such wrapper for NV21.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703596/mediacodec-and-camera-colorspaces-dont-match

Comment: Hi @Alex, I have tried to get my solution using FFmpegFrameFiter and OpenCV but was not able to do it. Finally, I have rotated YUVImage by converting it to Bitmap and rotating it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: … and you feed the Bitmap to MediaCodec?

Comment: Hi @Alex, No.. I am not using MediaCodec, instead I used MJPEG streaming approach and feed rotated bitmap for MJPEG stream.

Comment: I have to do streaming in LAN so I am also getting low latency using MJPEG.